# Recibo advertencia de error en php

Tags: php7

no logro resolver el siguiente tema.
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in.
El siguiente código es el cual trabajo.

```
<?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
```

Me dice que cambie _array por _ assoc y nada.

Answer (score 1):

La función `mysqli_query()` requiere que el primer parámetro sea un objeto de tipo conexión. Tú le has pasado `$conn`, que debería tener una conexión, si la conexión falla `$conn` será false, no un objeto de tipo conexión, que es lo que te está indicando el error: `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given` Es decir, revisa tu conexión y comprueba que se ha realizado correctamente:

```
if (!$conn) {
    die('Error de Conexión (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu participación..

Comment: Si lo has arreglado te recomiendo que marques la respuesta que te ha ayudado como aceptada. Si ninguna te ha ayudado y lo has resuelto de otra manera, pon la solución en una respuesta a tu propia pregunta y a las 24h la puedes marcar como respuesta aceptada. Así otras personas con el mismo problema podrán beneficiarse de la respuesta también :)

Answer (score 0):

Para comenzar nisiquiera tienes instanciado la conexion en tu archivo, para comenzar debes tenerla instanciada crear un o bjeto y ahora si ese pasarselo a tu query.

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

 $con = new conexion();//clase
 $conn = $con -> conectar();//método que contiene la funcion de conectar

     $sql = $conn -> query( "SELECT * FROM clientes" ); //query
     while($mostrar= $sql ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
          printf ( $row["valor_que_quieras_imprimir"]);
       }
 ?>
```

Comment: Tiene la conexión a la que haces referencia, en lo sucesivo pondre el codigo completo, gracias ..